# How to restrict HAProxy to serve only specific URI?

Tags: haproxy

I’m having some issues with an ACL that’s not working as intended. I have a service and I want to only allow very specific paths to be accessed. For example I want to allow access to [www.mysite.com/hello](http://www.mysite.com/hello) but not [www.mysite.com/bye](http://www.mysite.com/bye). However, I’m getting 403 forbidden even on /hello. Can someone help me with the syntax? For example, if I wanted to grant access to only these resources:

- [www.mysite.com/hello](http://www.mysite.com/hello)
- [www.mysite.com/images](http://www.mysite.com/images)
- [www.mysite.com/page?id=parameters](http://www.mysite.com/page?id=parameters)
- [www.mysite.com/page?id=ok](http://www.mysite.com/page?id=ok)
- [www.mysite.com/page?id=test](http://www.mysite.com/page?id=test)

I created the below:

```
acl myhost_host hdr(host) -i www.mysite.com

acl myhost_allowed_uri_paths path_beg,url_dec -i -m beg /hello | /images
acl myhost_allowed_uri_pages path_beg,url_dec -i -m beg /page
acl myhost_allowed_parm urlp(id) parameters | test | ok

http-request deny if myhost_host !myhost_allowed_uri_paths
http-request deny if myhost_host !myhost_allowed_uri_pages !myhost_allowed_parm
```